# Linq and object's wrapper

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a class `MyObj` that had a `Width` property.
I need to remove that property from MyObj to `MyObjWrapper` that will wrap MyObj.
I use it like this:

```
Dim _MyObjWrapper As MyObjWrapper = New MyObjWrapper(_myObj)
Dim theWidth as Integer = _MyObjWrapper.Width
```

To select specific widths of MyObj I used

```
Dim q = From mo In myContainer.GetMyObjs() 
        Where mo.Width > 50 
        Select mo.Width Distinct
```

Now, if the `Width` does not belong anymore to MyObj, I would like to use instead of *mo.Width* the *moWrapper.Width* :

```
Dim q = From mo In myContainer.GetMyObjs() 
        Where New MyObjWrapper(mo).Width > 50 
        Select New MyObjWrapper(mo).Width Distinct
```

Is there a way *do not* use 2 times the wrapper's constructor MyObjWrapper(mo)?

Comment: Look up the 'let' keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My VS install is acting crazy right now, so I couldn't test this, but try something like:

```
Dim q = From mo In myContainer.GetMyObjs() 
        Let someObj = New MyObjWrapper(mo)
        Where someObj.Width > 50 
        Select someObj.Width.Distinct
```